# gitlab shows wrong README on project page

Tags: git, gitlab

GitLab Community Edition 8.1.2

Having added a repo with a README.html file, I have subsequently removed that README and replaced it with a README.md.

But the project page is still showing the old README.html.  It's odd because if you try to edit the file by clicking on the pencil, I get a 404:

```
http://<our url>/<group>/<project>/edit/master/readme.html
```

It's obviously been cached somehow / somewhere.  Can anyone advise how to resolve this?  Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a webserver like nginx in front for proxying? They often cache content (had the same issue with my Jenkins).

Comment: @das_j By default GitLab uses nginx, either its own bundled installation or, optionally, an extant installation if you configure it to do so. However, in this case it's almost certainly that the README is intentionally cached in GitLab's Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab caches projects' README files because parsing MarkDown can be expensive and the READMEs are displayed on the Dashboard (and therefore displayed frequently). You could try [clearing the Redis cache](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/maintenance.html#clear-redis-cache):

For Omnibus installations:

```
sudo gitlab-rake cache:clear
```

For installations from source:

```
cd /home/git/gitlab
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
```

For Docker installations:

```
sudo docker exec gitlab gitlab-rake cache:clear
```